# How to remove border in Wordpress Avada Theme (The Event Calendar) on main Page?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to remove the border around the event picture and event title on my main Page ( [ofen49ers.de](https://ofen49ers.de) ).

[image: Event]

Adding a custom class to the section and changing the border value to 0 dosen't seem to work. Maybe someone has an idea to remove the border.

Here the CSS I used:

```
.custom-class-event-front {
  border: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
.fusion-events-shortcode .fusion-events-thumbnail, .fusion-events-shortcode .fusion-layout-column .fusion-column-wrapper {
    border-width: 0!important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
.post-content .fusion-column-wrapper, 
.fusion-events-thumbnail.hover-type-none 
 {
   border: none !important;
 }
</style>
```